# Fixing a C# race condition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, thread-safety, serial-port

I'm very new to threading and thus am not quite sure if this even is a race condition. I'm querying data from a serial device using C#'s SerialPort class. My understanding through reading around the internet is that this class spawns a separate thread when the data received event is fired. This seemed to be confirmed when the program would not let me set the value of text boxes in the event method since controls can only be set in the thread that created them. My issue is that I think a race condition exists in the way I am setting the textbox contents.

Using this method

```
private void btnWidth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mySerialManager.ClearErrorQueue();
    mySerialManager.WriteLine();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    if (mySerialManager.HasErrors())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an Error Accessing the Serial Device:\n\r" + PrintAllErrors(mySerialManager), "Serial Device Error");
        return;
    }

    btnSubmit.Enabled = true;
    btnSubmit.Select();
    txtMeasWidth.Text = myRecievedData.Substring(0, myRecievedData.Length - 1).Trim();
}
```

I write the data command to the serial device and then set the text box contents. The event handler sets the value of the myRecievedData string once it is fired. My question is how do I make sure that the event has been fired and has set this string's value before I write to the text box. I did this at the bottom of the method as sort of a quick fix, but I want to make sure that if this is a race condition it is taken care of.

Sorry this is so long winded. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are creating a race condition here.
But it is easily fixed.

In your `ComPortDataReceivedEventHandler` just invoke a method that will set your textbox with the appropriate text

For instance:

```
form.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() {textMeasWidth.Text = myreceivedData}))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that there's a race condition. You can use the [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method to safely update the text box from your SerialPort's event handler:

```
txtMeasWidth.Invoke((Action)delegate { txtMeasWidth.Text = myRecievedData; });
```

Comment: I tried using the invoke but it didn't ever actually do anything. Are there any issues associated with invoke? The one difference I see was that I was using the forms invoke instead of the text boxes. Maybe that was the issue?

Comment: No, calling Invoke on the form should have worked too. When you tried it, the delegate you passed to Invoke was never actually called?

Comment: Pretty much, it just ignored the line in all honesty, and if i tried to step through the code the debugger would freeze at that line.

Comment: I actually got it to work with invoke. I used the code in the other answer though since visual studio had some issues with your suggestion. I upvoted both answers since they were pretty much the same thing.

Comment: So this is strange. In the project I'm doing this in it would not let me make the cast to Action, it was only available as a generic type (ie Action<T>). But in my test project it would let me make that cast. Its something on my end obviously.

Comment: I think it's related to which version of the .NET Framework you're targeting. In .NET 3.5, `Action` is defined in System.Core.dll, so your code won't compile unless you add a reference to that. But in .NET 4.0, `Action` is defined in mscorlib.dll, which is always referenced. And in earlier versions of .NET, `Action` doesn't exist at all. OTOH, `MethodInvoker` exists in all versions of .NET.

Comment: Yea that's it then. I'm targeting 2.0 since that's what every program where I work targets.